# Im trying to add a Web Service to an already existing ASP.NET 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I added the web reference to my project,however an error 'Operation Timed out' appears.
Any idea what steps to follow???Its in 2.0....Kindly help

Comment: Have you hosted the web service on IIS or your service is in the same solution as the website?

Comment: im running it locally temporarily...havent hosted the project or the service on IIS...this is my service address 'http://localhost:3135/Service1.svc'

Comment: try opening the URL in browser window... with the same URL

Comment: I think your service is not running when you are connecting to it via the other app

Comment: the URL is opening in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

you should re-check web service alive or not ( via web service url )